# how to delete line from the XML file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl

how to delete only the line from xml file ( with sed/awk or perl one liner line )

that start with:

```
<units>
```

and ended with

```
</Networks>
```

as the follwoing

```
<units><unit ip= ............   </units><ranges/></Networks>
```

Comment: You understand that this leaves you with an xml file that is syntactically incorrect, i.e. you're missing the closing `</Networks>` tag by removing the line.

Comment: yes I know that ( the first Networks exist on the top of the file

Comment: Why do you need an ill formed XML file?

Comment: dont worry later I will append new lines that will be in place that line

Comment: Looks like an XY problem to me. What are you -actually- trying to accomplish? Parsing XML with regex is a bad idea, because there's lots of ways it can go wrong. Creating malformed XML deliberately is also a bad idea, for much the same reason. What problem are you trying to solve? I will probably suggest the answer is - use an XML parser, not a regex. With a bit more XML as a sample, this is actually very easy to do.

Comment: X posted to Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078801/how-to-add-content-of-variable-after-word-in-xml-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
perl -i -pe 's|^<units>.*</Networks>$||' /my/filename
```

Note that if you have leading or trailing space in the line you will need this instead:

```
perl -i -pe 's|^ *<units>.*</Networks> *$||' /my/filename
```

I uesd pipe as a separator rather than slash to avoid unnecessary escaping.

Comment: I'll now leave you to be partonised by the regulars: if you're an expert, you already know the issues, and if not you will learn them by trying this.

Comment: the units line is only the one unit line in the XML so I not see any problem here

Answer (score 4):

Do not use regular expressions to parse XML. It's an excellent way to create brittle code, because there's a bunch of perfectly valid things you can do with XML which will break a regex. Things like reformatting the XML in entirely valid ways (such as 'pretty printing' it in a nested/indented form) will break your code.

Instead I would suggest - use an XML parser. Personally, I like the [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) module in perl.

Your comment suggests that what you're trying to do is add stuff to a `<Networks>` element in your XML.

So how about something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml_text = '<XML>
<Networks><units><unit ip="1.2.3.4" /></units><ranges/></Networks>
</XML>';

my $parser = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented' );
#would probably use 'parsefile' instead here
$parser->parse($xml_text);

print "\nBefore:\n";
$parser->print;


#insert a new element into 'Networks':
$parser->root->first_child('Networks')->insert_new_elt(
        'last_child',     #position - end of "Networks" element
        'new_element',    #element
        {   'attribute_here'    => "value_here",
            'another_attribute' => 'another_value',
        },                 #attributes as key value pairs
        "Content_here",    #element content
    );


print "\nAfter:\n";
$parser->print;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicate that you are aware that this will break your XML, you can do what you want with one of these:

1. Perl

   ```
   perl -ne 'print unless m#^<units>.*</Networks>$#' file.xml 
   perl -ne 'm#^<units>.*</Networks>$# ? next : print' file.xml
   ```
2. awk

   ```
   awk '!/^<units>.*<\/Networks>$/' file.xml
   ```
3. sed

   ```
   sed '/^<units>.*<\/Networks>$/d' file.xml
   ```
4. grep

   ```
   grep -Ev '^<units>.*<\/Networks>$' file.xml
   ```
5. Bash (and zsh), for the sake of completion

   ```
   while read -r line; do 
       [[ "$line" =~ ^\<units\>.*\<\/Networks\>$ ]] || printf "%s\n" "$line"
   done < file.xml
   ```

Comment: The awk one is  a really (no pun intended) awkward way of doing it. Why not `awk '!/<units>.*<\/Networks>/'`

Comment: You need the `!` before it or else it will only print that line

Comment: @JID fixed,  I wrote too fast

Comment: Sorry, you are also missing the last `/` :(

Comment: @JID yes, that's what I get for editing on my phone. Thanks. Next time though, please edit the post directly to fix this sort of thing.

Comment: Sorry :( Last time i edited someones post they weren't happy at all. Will do though :)